# PHP variable is empty when writing to a CSV file

Tags: php, csv, variables

I am fetching an adress from a webapi endpont which returns me JSON:

```
$json_order = json_decode($order); 

  $InvoiceNumber = $json_order->Data->InvoiceNumber;
  $Company = $json_order->Data->ShippingAddress->Company;
  $Street = $json_order->Data->ShippingAddress->Street;
  $HouseNumber = $json_order->Data->ShippingAddress->HouseNumber;
  $Line2 = $json_order->Data->ShippingAddress->Line2;
  $Line3 = $json_order->Data->ShippingAddress->Line3;
  $City = $json_order->Data->ShippingAddress->City;
  $Zip = $json_order->Data->ShippingAddress->Zip;
  $Country = $json_order->Data->ShippingAddress->Country;
  $FirstName = $json_order->Data->ShippingAddress->FirstName;
  $LastName = $json_order->Data->ShippingAddress->LastName;

echo $InvoiceNumber; //returns 4570 (int)
echo $Company; //returns Test Company (string)
```

now I want to write this data to a CSV file with

```
$list = array (

array('Referenz','Name Absender','Nachname Absender','Firma Absender','Adresse Absender 1','Adresse 
Absender 2','PLZ Absender','Ort Absender','Staat Absender','Land Absender','Telefon Absender','Email 
Absender','Name Empfaenger','Nachname Empfaenger','Firma Empfaenger','Versandadresse 
1','Versandadresse 

2','PLZ Empfaenger','Region Empfaenger','Staat Empfaenger','Land Empfaenger','Telefon 
Empfaenger','Email 
Empfaenger','Versicherung','Ware','Warenwert','Breite','Laenge','Hoehe','Gewicht'),

array($Company,$InvoiceNumber,'test',$Street, $Firstname) /*and so on*/
);

$fp = fopen('file.csv', 'w');

foreach ($list as $fields) {
                            fputcsv($fp, $fields, ";", '"');
                           }
fclose($fp);
```

When I echo the variables they will show up (I added echo command in my code). But when I want them to be written to my CSV, they will NOT show up. What am I missing here? I tried a lot of things.

Comment: Does `file.csv` exist, and if so what are it's permissions set to?

Comment: Your "echo" comment is quite confusing. Can you just add those echo statements to the code + their output?

Comment: fyi, `'$Firstname'` will write `$Firstname` to your .csv. Other than that the code looks ok, make double sure the variables are actually filled. Does your header (`'Referenz','Name Absender'...`) get written to the file?

Comment: Your code works fine. It is most probably due to permission issue. Check you can write to `file.csv` file.

Comment: File permission is correct. The CSV is generated and shows header and the string 'test'. I added the echo command in the code. I edited the var $Firstname and removed the apostrophes.